# How can I merge rows and columns from two sql tables into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I searched for a while but I couldn't find something similar.
I have two tables with data and I want to merge those two in two one.

```
Tbl1
id nr val1
1  a1  123
2  a2  124
3  a3  125

Tbl2
id nr val2
5  a1  223
6  a2  224
7  a4  225
```

Resulting table should be something like this.

```
Tbl
nr val1 val2
a1  123  223
a2  124  224
a3  125    0
a4    0  225
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

It is MS SQL and I tried union and join. But they don't do.

Comment: Tag Database you are using and what have u tried so far, Stack overflow is not free code writing service

Comment: A little search on `inner join` would be useful

Comment: You're going to need a full outer join here, but first show us your query attempt and tell us which database you are using.  Stack Overflow is not a homework service.

Comment: @BHouse Inner join won't work here.

Comment: Or a UNION ALL combined with GROUP BY.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Full Outer Join looks to work, thanks. I tired left, right and cross join and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `COALESCE` the columns together.

```
SELECT COALESCE(tbl1.nr,tbl2.nr) AS nr,tbl1.val1,tbl2.val2 
FROM tbl1 FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.nr = tbl2.nr;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use MS SQL then you could try full outer join and Isnull function to get the result you need.

```
SELECT Isnull(tbl1.nr, tbl2.nr) nr, 
    Isnull(tbl1.val1, 0) val1,
      Isnull(Tbl2.val2, 0) val2 FROM tbl1 FULL OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.nr = tbl2.nr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NVL(a1.nr,b1.nr) as nr,
       NVL(a1.val1,0) AS val1,
       NVL(b1.val2,0) AS val2
FROM table1 a1
     FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b1 ON a1.nr = b1.nr
ORDER BY a1.nr;
```

Comment: Try to use White space when posting SQL. SQL is a multiline language, and posting your entire query on one line can make it very difficult to read. Also, `NVL` isn't a valid fucntion in SQL Server, so this answer won't help the OP.